# Extracting integers from a mixed list

Tags: python, xlrd, xlwt

I am trying to read from a csv file, extract some values and copy them to an already existing file.

The rows in my file look like this:

```
row = ['success', '9358', 'MC', '9363.0', 'MC', '1.001', '9363.0', 'MC', '1.001']
```

I am trying to extract the integer value 9358 and I have tried following things:

1. `int(row[1])`
2. `map(int, row[1])`
3. `map(int, row['1'])`
4. `int(row[1].replace("'", ""))`

The error for `int(row[1])` is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "upv_c.py", line 26, in
    num1 = int(row[1])
      ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
```

But every one of these throws some error or the other.
Any idea how can I go about it?

My code is as follows:

```
#!/home/utils/Python-2.7/bin/python2.7
import csv
import xlwt
import xlrd
from xlutils.copy import copy
book = xlrd.open_workbook('reg_test.xls')
wb = copy(book) # a writable copy 
w_sheet = wb.get_sheet(0)
with open('results2.csv', 'r') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    next(reader, None)
    next(reader, None)
    next(reader, None)
    next(reader, None)
    i = 1
    for row in reader:
        num = map(int, row[1])
        w_sheet.write(i, 2, num)
        i += 1
wb.save('reg_test.xls')
```

Comment: "But every one of these throws some error or the other." <- Don't leave us guessing. What errors?

Comment: Ok, so why are you doing `num1 = int(row[6])` instead of `num1 = int(row[1])`?

Comment: Sorry!The real list was too long to post. I made sure there was no error in indexing.

Comment: Well the problem is that there's just an empty string at index 6.

Comment: No! That was a mistake. The real this is row[1].

Comment: Ok, but then the problem is still that there's an empty string, just at index 1 :)

Comment: When you describe your input file, is that LITERALLY how a row in the file looks?  i.e. a row starts with the letter 'r', then the letter 'o'. then the letter 'w', then a space, etc. ?  Or is that the Python representation of a row after it is read and processed?

Comment: Here is how it looks:
1,,afi.rd.8B4A#d4304636,mc_perf_standsim_auto_lpddr4_200.tl#8,success,8772,MC,8737.0,MC,0.996,8737.0,MC,0.996,

Comment: @user3262537 Item 1 in that list is blank. Remember lists are zero-indexed.

Comment: In that data, the first integer is in row[0].  row[1] is indeed a blank space.  (Python lists indexes start at zero, not one.)

Answer (score 0):

What error you getting exactly ? you should not get an error if you trying to convert a actual number string. Try a try catch block to see what's happening.

```
try:
for row in reader:
    num = map(int, row[5])
    w_sheet.write(i, 2, num)
    i += 1
except Exception, e:
    print 'Unable to convert', row[5]
```

Comment: Unable to convert
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "upv_c.py", line 33, in <module>
    print 'Unable to convert', row[5]

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
if row.isnumeric():
    my_var = int(row)
```

This way you can ensure that your string argument is in fact numeric before passing it to `int()`.

Answer (score 0):

I see your number is enclosed in '' like '123'
and when you are trying to read in python it is read as "'123'" in a variable

```
temp=row[1].replace("'","")
```

then

```
num = int(temp)
```